# Have an ordered array, how to plot x_i versus x_i+1?

Tags: arrays, matlab, vector, plot, sequence

I have an ordered set of values. The values are defined as i=1, 2, 3,...(i.e. the first value in the array 1408 is i=1, second value 1380 is i=2, and so on). Then, I need to plot i versus i+1. So, essentially, I'm plotting consecutive data points against each other.

I know how to plot data points, but I am not sure how to make it so I am plotting consecutive data points. Should I split the array into two?

Sorry if the explanation is confusing. Would really appreciate any help on this!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with:

```
plot(array(1:end-1),array(2:end));
```

This will plot 1 against 2, 2 against 3, 3 against 4, etc.

Comment: Ohh, okay. What about i versus i+2, then? Would it be plot(array(1:end-2), array(2:end))? Thanks so much! New to coding.

Comment: Close! You've got the first bit right, but you would want to use `array(3:end)` for the second part of the plot command.

Answer (score 0):

Another thing you can do:

```
plot(array, lagmatrix(array, 1))
```